# "no such file or directory" with perl system calls

Tags: macos, perl, sed, du, timemachine

I am trying to run a Perl script that reads in filenames from stdin and calls du using a system command. When I run the du command on the commandline it works fine but when du is called in the perl script using system() I get "No such file or directory." The filename does have spaces and an apostrophe which I escape before passing it into the perl script. The perl script itself is VERY simple:

```
use strict; use warnings;
my $line1;
my @tmutil_args;

while($line1 = <>){
    @tmutil_args = ("du", "-sh", $line1);
    system(@tmutil_args);
}
```

I also use a shell script to escape the filename. The one line script is as follows:

```
s/[\' ]/\\&/g
```

a sample filename before and after it is run through sed is:

```
/Volumes/Mac Mini Backup 4TB/Backups.backupdb/John's Mac Mini/2015-06-04-132645

/Volumes/Mac\ Mini\ Backup\ 4TB/Backups.backupdb/Pete\'s\ Mac\ Mini/2015-06-04-132645
```

I have tried with and without escaping the spaces and apostrophe.

the output is:

```
du: /Volumes/Mac\ Mini\ Backup\ 4TB/Backups.backupdb/Pete\'s\ Mac\ Mini/2015-06-04-132645
: No such file or directory
```

one important thing, I am running this on a mac OS X 10.95 in a terminal window. Perl v5.16.2

you might ask what I am trying to do. I am trying to get the size of the individual Mac TimeMachine backups.

so can anyone tell me what I need?

Comment: There is a newline at the end of each filename.  Or, rather, there isn't.

Comment: `quotemeta` is your friend here. http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/quotemeta.html

Comment: With the list form of `system` you shouldn't need to escape filenames.

Answer (score 3):

The error message tells you what you need.  It is trying to open a file whose name ends with `\n`.  Try `chomp`.

But really you should be using find w/--exec or xargs, or traversing in perl with `File::Find`.  This is an extremely fragile way to accomplish your goals.

```
find /path/to/root/dir -type f -exec du -sh {} \;
```

Comment: Don't `chop` try `chomp`

Comment: The newlines are guaranteed to be there, and this is exactly when `chop` is appropriate.

Comment: On the other hand, the performance gain of `chop` over `chomp` is totally irrelevant here, so there's no reason to avoid `chomp` other than losing a stroke in code golf.

Comment: @WilliamPursell: `chomp` is the correct call. If the input is terminated with `Ctrl-D` instead of `Enter` then there will be no trailing newline. `chop` has its place but it isn't here

Comment: unfortunately, the list cannot be retrieved from find. I rely on tmutil, a TimeMachine utility, to generate the list. 
thanks

Comment: I removed the necessity of tmutil. find words great. It's just amazing what you can do with find!

Answer (score 1):

The contents  of `$line1` includes the newline that you typed to terminate the string. That will cause a mismatch if you try to find a file with that name, so remove it using `chomp`

It is also best to declare your variables as *late* as possible — preferably at their first point of use — and not in a block at the top of the program

```
use strict;
use warnings;

while ( my $filename = <> ) {
    chomp $filename;
    system('du', '-sh', $filename);
}
```